# What is the best prediction measure when the dependent variable has a high autocorrelation?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, measure

I am working on predicting a dependent variable on a panel data.

I need to choose the prediction measure however I have the following issues:

- I am working with a panel data and therefore mixing time steps and different individuals
- The dependent variable is highly autocorrelated (the dependent variable is a yearly measure that I shift on a monthly basis and therefore is highly autocorrelated and sometimes has the same value for a number of periods)

I worked with the R-squared, however, I believe there is some perverse effect due to the previous points and looking for a correction of the measure.

Thank you.